# Diagonals in Proteus Isis?

Tags: proteus

Is it possible to draw diagonal circuit connections in Proteus Isis? I can only seem to get right angles, and a particular bit of my design would look a lot clearer if I used a couple of diagonals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, just disable the wire autorouter by pressing the menu button or by using the tools menu or by using the "w" key shortcut.

[image]